# Long subscript handling

Tags: subscripts

I wan to get basically this expression

[image]

The problem, if I don't do much, is the big space on the subscript
[image]

The best I have been to do is (from where I erase the top part to make the first picture)

[image]

I have two problems with this expression; first the vertical line is too big (if I don't use \bigg| it overlaps with the text) and second in the equation environment it gives

[image]

which is not what I want.

The code for the three las pictures is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
(p+q)_\mu\left.\tensor*{\tilde\Gamma}{^\mu_a^\nu_b^\rho_c}\right|_{\text{regulated}} (-p-q,p,q)
\end{equation}

$
(p+q)_\mu\tensor*{\tilde\Gamma}{^\mu_a^\nu_b^\rho_c}\mathop{\bigg|(-p}_{\mathclap{\text{regulated}}} -q,p,q)
$

\begin{equation}
(p+q)_\mu\tensor*{\tilde\Gamma}{^\mu_a^\nu_b^\rho_c}\mathop{\bigg|(-p}_{\mathclap{\text{regulated}}} -q,p,q)
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried \parbox{0pt}{regulated}?

Comment: it does work, but when I tried it in the whole text, it didn't because \parbox and the breqn package seems not to be compatible. (I use breqn in other parts)

Comment: Please edit your code so that it incorporates use of the `breqn` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\mathclap` is a *c*entered over*lap* which forces you to add `(-p`. Instead you can use `\mathrlap`, where the text only overlaps on the *r*ight side.
Using this in the subscript of `\biggr|` leads to

```
\begin{equation}
  (p+q)_\mu\tensor*{\tilde\Gamma} {^\mu_a^\nu_b^\rho_c}\biggr|_{\mathrlap{\text{regulated}}} (-p-q,p,q)
\end{equation}
```

[image]

This works in display and inline math, but the line is still too big.
The problem is that delimiters are always centered around the math axis in TeX.
If you use LuaTeX, you can use the `noaxis` flag to fix this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  (p+q)_\mu\left.\tensor*{\tilde\Gamma}{^\mu_a^\nu_b^\rho_c}\Uright noaxis|_{\mathrlap{\text{regulated}}} (-p-q,p,q)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]